# Mitigating "type-validate then use" code duplication pattern

Tags: c++, json, code-duplication

One of modules of the system deals with a JSON-based protocol that is used to transfer a wide variety of data. This results in almost a hundred of small sections of code that look like this:

```
 /*
  * Data package Foo reports Fooness level
  */
 if(root.isMember("foo") && root["foo"].isInt())
 {
     int foo = root["foo"].asInt();
     // do things with foo
 }


 /*
  * Data package Bar gives ID number and name of a newly arrived bar.
  */
 if(root.isMember("bar") && root["bar"].isObject())
 {
     JSON::Value bar = root["bar"];

     if(bar.isMember("baz") && bar["baz"].isString()
     && bar.isMember("buzz") && bar["buzz"].isInt())
     {
          std::string baz = bar["baz"].asString();
          int buzz = bar["buzz"].asInt();
         // do things with baz and buzz

     }
     else{ err["bar"] = argument_error; }
 }
```

Not only is the "flesh" of each block often a line or two with some 10 lines of parameter validation, this leads to countless copy-paste errors and maintainability problems (a key changes name, it must be changed in some 6 places).

How would you reshape these patterns to do what they do without all that code duplication?
(note, all main keys and few sub-keys are optional, most sub-keys are obligatory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't list out the types of things like `bar`, so I'm just using `Bar` for that type.

You can give yourself some helper methods, making use of status codes or exceptions, depending on how common you expect failures to be.

```
bool get_string(std::string& result, const Bar& bar, const char* name)
{
  if(bar.isMember(name) && bar[name].isString())
  {
    result = bar[name].asString();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// and similarly
bool get_int(int& result, const Bar& bar, const char* name)
{
  if(bar.isMember(name) && bar[name].isInt())
  {
    result = bar[name].asInt();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then you can use it with:

```
JSON::Value bar;
std::string baz;
int buzz;
if(get_object(bar, root, "bar"))
{
  if (get_string(baz, bar, "baz")
      && get_int(buzz, bar, "buzz"))
  {
     // do things with baz and buzz
  }
  else{ err["bar"] = argument_error; }
}
```

Which is slightly cleaner, but not by leaps and bounds.  If you expect the things you're looking for to be present, and failures are unlikely, then we can use exceptions.  And we can go all out with templates too:

```
// set up template forms to check types
template<typename T> bool is_a(const Bar& b);
template<> bool is_a<std::string>(const Bar& b) { return b.isString(); }
template<> bool is_a<int>        (const Bar& b) { return b.isInt();    }
template<> bool is_a<JSON::Value>(const Bar& b) { return b.isObject(); }

// templates to extract as a type
template<typename T> T as_type(const Bar& b);
template<> std::string as_type<std::string>(const Bar& b) { return b.asString(); }
template<> int         as_type<int>        (const Bar& b) { return b.asInt();    }
template<> JSON::Value as_type<JSON::Value>(const Bar& b) { return b.asObject(); }

// the one extraction method
template<typename T>
T get(const Bar& bar, const char* name)
{
  if ( ! bar.isMember(name))  throw std::runtime_error("not a member");
  if ( ! is_a<T>(bar[name]))  throw std::runtime_error("wrong type");
  return as_type<T>(bar[name]);
}

// and now we use it
try
{
  JSON::Value bar = get<JSON::Value>(root, "bar");
  std::string baz = get<std::string>(bar, "baz");
  int buzz = get<int>(bar, "buzz");
  // do things with baz and buzz
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& exc)
{
  err["bar"] = argument_error;
}
```

The setup requires more methods, but now using it is very simple and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to automate the naming of identifiers, you're basically down to using the preprocessor. You could try something like this:

```
#define FOO(var, name, cpp, json) cpp name((var.isMember(#name) && var[#name].is##json) ? var[#name].as##json() : "[ERROR in " #name "]")
```

```c++
int main()
{
  FOO(bar, foo, std::string, String);

  // translates into:
  std::string foo((bar.isMember("foo") && bar["foo"].isString) ? bar["foo"].asString() : "[ERROR in " "foo" "]");
}
```